# Constructing a random Experiment

Tags: density-function, random-generation

Can someone help me as how to construct a random experiment which has the following density:$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}+e^{\frac{-(x-10)^2}{2}}\right)$$

Update: According to what I understood , I am giving an R code, please check @MikeP whether this is right or not..

$x=$numeric$(n)$

$z=$numeric$(n)$

$y=$numeric$(n/2)$

$>x=$rnorm$(n)\ \ \ \#$ here is the number of numbers we want to generate

$>y=$sample$(1:n,n/2)$

$>$for$(i$ in $1:n)\{$

$+f=0$

$+$for$(j$ in $1:n/2)$

$+f=$ ifelse$(i==y[j],1,0)$

$+z[i]=$ ifelse$(f==0,x[i],x[i]+10)\}$

Comment: In order to answer this question, it would be formidable if you could provide a range that $x$ can take. Then, one would integrate over this range of $x$ to obtain the CDF, say $F(x) = y$. One can then apply random sampling by (1) finding the inverse function $F^{-1}(y) = x$, (2) taking $N$ draws from a Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, say $y_1, ..., y_N$, and (3) taking $F^{-1}(y_i) = x_i, \forall 1 \leq i \leq N$ as your random sample.

Comment: @Jeremias K : I understood your method very well. But what am I to do if the pdf is 1) not integrable and even if it is integrable 2) not invertible easily?

Comment: You can solve both problems by numerical methods. Take the numerical integral and inverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a generator for normally distributed (gaussian) random numbers?  Such as randn in matlab?

If so, add 10 to a random half of the numbers and you're there.  The pdf above is simply the sum of two (scaled by 1/2) gaussians (both with sigma=1, one with mean 0 and one with mean 10).

Comment: I think what you are saying is wrong. The procedure you suggest would be the addition of two independent gaussians, but the provided pdf does not specify two argumets ($x, y$, say).

Comment: We wouldn't have to add gaussians, just add 10 to the gaussian output half the time.  Since the 'two' gaussians making up the given pdf have the same variance, all we have to do is change the mean for half of them.

Comment: Neat! Yes, I guess that would work!